# jQuery Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Html:

```
h4
  | Users
    button.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs.check_button aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
     span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down aria-hidden="true"

.hsep

.form-group
  == collection_check_boxes :group, :user_ids, User.all, :id, :login do |b|
    == "<div class='checkbox'>#{b.label { b.check_box + b.text }}</div>"

h4
  | Domains
    button.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs.check_button aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
     span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down aria-hidden="true"

.hsep

.form-group
  == collection_check_boxes :group, :domain_ids, Domain.all, :id, :domain_name do |b|
    == "<div class='checkbox'>#{b.label { b.check_box + b.text }}</div>"
```

Javascript:

```
$(".check_button").on("click", ->
 cbxs = $('h4 ~ .form-group').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]')
 cbxs.prop("checked", !cbxs.prop("checked"))
)
```

So it's a form where I got two checkbox list and I want a button for a each of them to check/uncheck all but I want this button to be generic as it's present in multiple views.

The javascript works fine but as you may have noticed, if the 2nd button is clicked, it checks/unchecks boxes from the first `collection_check_boxes` because of my `$('h4  ~ .form-group')` selector.

So what I want is not to use a raw `h4` selector but use something like `$(this).parent()`first which will give me the right `h4` element, my problem is how do I use `$('h4  ~ .form-group')` then?
I can't make it work because I only know how to use it directly with `h4` but I don't know how to actually change the `h4`.

It's a pretty simple problem I guess but I don't see how to use the `jQuery( "prev ~ siblings" )` selector while changing my `h4`.

Comment: As a side-note, that **is not HTML**, it's a template language.  Would be nice to see the rendered HTML rather than the template markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify *the h4 that is the parent* of the clicked box.

One way to accomplish this is using [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) combined with [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$(".check_button").on("click", ->
 cbxs = $(this).closest('h4').nextAll('.form-group').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]')
 cbxs.prop("checked", !cbxs.prop("checked"))
)
```